# Using jQuery $.when and $.then to handle multiple ajax requests not returning response text

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, xml

Essentially I want to use jQuery to return data from an XML and JSON feed and `console.log` the data only when both are successful.

If I comment out `getRoomFeed()` within the `$.whe`n it will return the proper `responseText` object for the XML, however if I leave both of them in there it returns the document object when I `console.log(rateData)`. Why can't I pull data from both the JSON and XML and get the `responseText` from both? Why do I get a different result when I use both feeds within the `$.when`?

See attached codepen and check the console or code below,

```
function getRoomFeed() {
 return $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "JSONURLHERE.json",
dataType: "JSON"
 });
};

 function getRates() {
  return $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "XMLURLHERE.xml",
dataType: "XML"
 });
};

$('#prop__selector').on('change', function() {
  getPropCode = $(this).val();
  $.when(getRoomFeed(), getRates()).then(function(roomData, rateData) {
console.log(roomData);
console.log(rateData);
    }); 
 });
```

http://codepen.io/benweiser/pen/gPNVmd/

I had attached images, but unfortunately I had to remove them because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine, but you're getting the three arguments from `$.ajax` in each response, so you need to do

```
console.log(roomData[0]);
console.log(rateData[0]);
```

And as jQuery parses the content when you add the dataType, the JSON is already parsed as an object, and the XML as a `document`, which is probably the document you're seeing.